# gcp http-health-check fails when forcing redirecting to `www.`

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm using GCP, & I want to force redirecting all my site's traffic from `example.com` to `www.example.com`, so I'm using a simple redirect in my Nginx configuration like:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;
    return      301         https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri; #permanent;
    }
    #Other configurations
}
```

(this Nginx configuration is inside my instances in a loadbalancer's backend service, where the loadbalancer's frontend has the ssl certificate)

But now GCP's default http-health-check is not working because it is waiting for a `200` response, not the `301` I'm responding with,

So, how to make the `www.` redirect with using the http-health-check?

Comment: 1/2) Is your backend HTTP, HTTPS or both? If your backend is HTTP, then you need to process the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` header to detect when the client connected using HTTPS and not redirect to HTTPS.

Comment: 2/2) Your redirect is to HTTP. Change to redirect to an  HTTPS URL.

Comment: Post your edit. If your health check is HTTP, it won't work. You need to create an HTTPS health check. Your question is short on the details of your configuration.

Comment: My load balancer receives HTTP & HTTPS traffic where it has the ssl certificate details, I've just updated my question with HTTPS redirection part, & my instances handles only HTTP traffic

Comment: Is Nginx your frontend or backend or in the middle? What is your health check? Details are required.

Comment: I'm using GCP's default http health check (port 80), & just updated the question with more details about where the Nginx configuration exists .. is it more clear now?

Comment: If you are redirecting HTTP port 80, you cannot health check port 80 using HTTP.

Comment: Exactly, that was my question, how to force the `www.` redirect with health checking the HTTP-80 ?

Comment: You are missing the point. You cannot. If you want to health check a backend, you need to select a port and protocol that responds as expected. Since you are redirecting HTTP port 80 (notice the word HTTP), you have two choices. Create a path based rule that does not redirect OR use a different protocol such as TCP. However, you refuse to provide the exact details of your configuration, so I cannot answer at this point which to implement.

Comment: I tried to update the question with the configuration you asked for as far as I understood from your questions, you don't expect anyone to just copy/paste a whole file in here!, so if any specific configuration is needed here to clarify the situation more, I'll be glad to provide.

Comment: I cannot help further.

Comment: Then thanks a lot for your contribution so far, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it :) , I changed the Nginx configuration mentioned here in the question to the following:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri; #permanent;
    }

    # to force adding 'www.' without bothering GCP health checks which connects with direct IP
    if ($host = "example.com") {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri; #permanent;
    }

    #Other configurations
}
```

the trick here is to check for `$host` variable, while normal user would type `example.com` to open the site, the GCP health checks will use direct IP to connect, so they won't see the `301` redirection